# Reviewing posts, rendered output diffs is not enough

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, page-rendering

While reviewing posts I'd sometimes like to just have a rendered output of the original and the edited post -that is without red & green diff text-

So basically I propose to have the following compare diff modes while reviewing posts:

- rendered output diffs
- rendered output
- markdown diffs

Comment: You are aware that you already can switch between rendered output diffs and markdown diffs, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe that the OP understands that and is just asking that a third option be added. Personally I have found some times where I wanted to see the difference between the rendered output but the green & red highlighting made it a bit difficult to see the differences.

Comment: @Jack: Perhaps, but I'd like to see that explicitly stated. It won't be the first time someone missed the existing diff options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes I know I can switch between rendered output diffs and markdown diffs, but as Jack notes, sometimes the red and green markup in rendered diff mode makes it difficult to see the differences.